# Update method doesn't work in Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a table that contains some website configs. And its model class like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class WebsiteConfig extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'website_config';
    protected $id = 'id';
    protected $allowedFields = [
        'config_name', 'config_value', 'updated_date'
    ];
}
```

And the table looks:
[Table Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5Ujj.jpg)

I want to update 'title' on this table. And codeigniter 4 documentation shows:

```
$data = [
    'title' => $title,
    'name'  => $name,
    'date'  => $date,
];

$builder->where('id', $id);
$builder->update($data);
```

But, when i use this usage, error occurs. My code:

```
    class Home extends BaseController
    {
        public function index()
        {
            $websiteConfig = new WebsiteConfig();
            try {
                $websiteConfig
                    ->where('config_name', 'title')
                    ->update('test');
            } catch (\ReflectionException $e) {
            }
            exit;
        }
    }
```

And the error:
[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1kem.jpg)

When i use the update method with set('config_value','test') function, the code is working without errors. But i want to update as shown on documentation. What can i do? Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/models/model.html#saving-data):

> **update()**
>
> Updates an existing record in the database. The first parameter is the $primaryKey of the record to update. An associative array of data is passed into this method as the second parameter. The array’s keys must match the name of the columns in a $table...

This means that calling `...->update('test')` will consider the string `'test'` the primary key and there's no data to update with.

If you want to update based on another field (not the primary key), then you have to use `set()` and then `update()` (without any arguments).

Also, `set()` must be called with either an associative array (field => value pairs) or separate key and value arguments.

Comment: But there is no key inside on the documentation's update method. There is just $data array as first parameter. This is what confused me. When i do samething like there, again doesn't work.

Comment: Which documentation are you looking at? https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/models/model.html#saving-data lists 3 examples for `update()`: the first is one primary key and the data array, the second is multiple primary keys and a data array, finally the 3rd example shows how to use `set()` together with `update()` (when you want to update based on some other field, not the primary key).

Comment: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#updating-data on this link, $builder->update() section. Could you look that?

Comment: That is the generic query builder class. In your code above, `WebsiteConfig` is a model and you are trying to use the `update()` method of it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass data in associative array format to update function, you are passing string only and because of first parameter is id you need to put it null here in controller

Many approaches here
1st approach

```
 class Home extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $websiteConfig = new WebsiteConfig();
        $data = array('config_value'=>'test');
        try {
           $websiteConfig
            ->where('config_name', 'title')
            ->update(null,$data);
        } catch (\ReflectionException $e) {
        }
        exit;
    }
}
```

2nd approach

```
namespace App\Controllers;
use App\Models\WebsiteConfig;
class Home extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $websiteConfig = new WebsiteConfig();
        $data = array('config_value'=>'test');
        try {
            $websiteConfig  
                ->whereIn('config_name', ['title'])
                ->set( $data)
                ->update();
                
        } catch (\ReflectionException $e) {
        }
        exit;
    }
}
```

3rd approach will be created function in model then call function from controller
model page

```
namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class WebsiteConfig extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'website_config';
    protected $id = 'id';
    protected $allowedFields = [
        'config_name', 'config_value', 'updated_date'
    ];
    
    function updateData($data,$tableName){
         $this->db->table($tableName)
                ->where('config_name', 'title')
                ->update($data);
                
    }
    
}
```

controller page

```
namespace App\Controllers;
use App\Models\WebsiteConfig;
class Home extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $websiteConfig = new WebsiteConfig();
        $data = array('config_value'=>'test');
        try {
            $websiteConfig->updateData($data,'website_config');
        } catch (\ReflectionException $e) {
        }
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: @emrez edited my code for many approaches, first same was same only change is putting first parameter as null in update function

Answer (score 0):

This is easier now in CodeIgniter 4. All you have to do is call `$model->update($idOfRecord, ['column_name', 'new_value']);`.

Your code then would look like this.

```
$id = 1; //if the id of the record you want to update is 1
$data = ['title' => 'test'];
$websiteConfig->update($id, $data);
```

This will update the value of the `title` column to `test` for the record with id of `1`. The `->update()` part of the code requires two parameters, the record `id` and an array of the columns with the values you want to save.

You can refer to this page from the User Guide here: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/models/model.html#saving-data